# Make Checkboxes behave like radio buttons for each table row independently

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with x numbers of rows and one columns with 3 checkboxes.
I want the user to select just 1 out of the 3 options. I tried using JQuery but the problem I have is that if I select one of the three options and then select another option which is the same but in another row, the option I previously selected get unchecked.

So I want the user to select 1 out of the 3 options but I want this to work indenpentdently for each row no matter how many rows the table has.

this is my code:

```js
$(".chb").change(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".chb").prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dtBasicExample">
       <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Aceptation</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>
            <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Total' value='Total'>Total<br>
           <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Parcial' value='Partial'>Partial<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Rechazo' value='Reject'>Reject
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>
            <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Total' value='Total'>Total<br>
           <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Parcial' value='Partial'>Partial<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Rechazo' value='Reject'>Reject
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>
            <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Total' value='Total'>Total<br>
           <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Parcial' value='Partial'>Partial<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Rechazo' value='Reject'>Reject
            </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
      <tfoot>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a Stack Snippet so we can see how it runs?

Comment: Inside the function, replace `$(".chb")` with `$(this).parent().find(".chb")`

Comment: If you use the radio button names to define groups, you shouldn't need the javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: @ChrisG that was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Use `siblings()` as suggested by @Juan Castillo

When you uncheck the other boxes, limit your search to the siblings (HTML elements that share a direct parent element) of the checkbox that was changed. Also, get rid of 
`$(".chb").prop('checked', false);` and `$(this).prop('checked', true);` The first line will uncheck every the box every time (not what you want) and the second line means you can't click on a box to uncheck it manually (seems unintentional).

```js
$(".chb").change(function() {
  $(this).siblings().prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dtBasicExample">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Aceptation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Total' value='Total'>Total<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Parcial' value='Partial'>Partial<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Rechazo' value='Reject'>Reject
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Total' value='Total'>Total<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Parcial' value='Partial'>Partial<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Rechazo' value='Reject'>Reject
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Total' value='Total'>Total<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Parcial' value='Partial'>Partial<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Rechazo' value='Reject'>Reject
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: you use `siblings()` instead of `parent().children('.chb').not(this)` , it will give you all elements that are the same level excluding the caller